# OleDbDataAdapter Fill method importing more rows

Tags: c#, datatable, fill, oledbdataadapter

I'm importing excel into DataTable. The excel file contains 50x7 cells with data.
The problem is that the Fill() method imports 368(?) rows regardless the fact that the data is in the first 50 of them. Any idea what might be the problem ?

I'm using OleDbDataAdapter for the import.

```
 connectionString = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + filename + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
 string  commandString = "select * from [" + worksheetName + "]";
 OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(commandString, connectionString);
 DataTable fileTable = new DataTable();
 adapter.Fill(fileTable);
```

Comment: Have you tried deleting rows from 51 to 369; in the Excel worksheet, to see if this clears the problem?

Comment: What means deleting rows in Excel? There are blank rows and when I scroll down in the file more rows appear. I don't think they're in the file for real. Correct me if I'm wrong please

Comment: I've had similar problems with Excel sheets whereby it looks like there isn't anything in the rows, but for some reason they get acted upon when being imported.  Even though it looks like there isn't something to delete, it's always worth a try.

Comment: I belive if you add formatting to cells they are now considered to "exist"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to remove empty cells from the `DataTable`:

```
adapter.Fill(fileTable);
fileTable = fileTable.AsEnumerable()
           .Where(row => !row.ItemArray.All(f => f is System.DBNull || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(f.ToString())))
           .CopyToDataTable();
```

Note that it also removes empty rows inside the sheet.

Comment: 'System.Data.DataTable' does not contain a definition for 'AsEnumerable' and no extension method 'AsEnumerable' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataTable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: If you're using .NET 2.0 or lower, you cannot use LINQ. Then you can build your DataTable manually via a OleDbCommand's reader.

Comment: @DimitarTsonev: I assume that you need to add a reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll`.